# WPF chart control change **series** title in legend

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, charts

[image]

How to change series to another word?
And I need help with adding two properties with one chart (example: a persons height and weight)

Comment: _And I need help with adding two properties with one chart_ What do you mean by that? You can add another series or two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default the `Name` property of each `Series` is displayed but you can also display something else in the `Legend` by setting the `LegendText` property:

```
yourSeries.Name = "PersData";
yourSeries.LegendText= "Height & Weight";
```

Note that the `Name` property can also be used to index the `Series`:

```
yourChart.Series["PersData"].LegendText =  "Height & Weight";
```

To display more categories you can add more `Series`:

```
Series S2 = yourChart.Series.Add("anotherSeriesName");    
Series S3 = yourChart.Series.Add("yetAnotherSeriesName");
```

Comment: thank you. but i'm asked to do this in MVVM pattern. if you can help me @TaW

Comment: Well, the property names are always the same, just the way/responsilbilty of accessing them may vary. I'm not proficient in WPF/MVVM, unfortunately. The best would be to ask a new question, including __some__ code you tried and specifying __explicitly__ that you need a solution using MVVM-pattern. Also try to ask only one question per post!